# When or why convert a numeric variable to factor?

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting

I am quite new in R and sort of learning by myself. I have a data set with 43 variables and I want to forecast one of theme. Some are numeric variables and some are factor variables.

The question is that I don't know when someone should convert factors to numerics and vice versa. I found on internet that you should not keep variables as numeric if they always take integer values and in a narrow range. (For exemple if the values are always between 1 and 7).

On of my variables is "NSM" and it represents number of seconds since midnight for each day. The value are integer and discrete (61200 61800 62400 63600 64200 65400 66000 66600 68400 69000 69600 70800 72000 72600 73200 etc you can observe that there is a 600 step).
They go from 0 to 85800.

So I want to have the opinion of someone more experienced than me (I have 0). Should I keep NSP numerci or convert it to factor and then groups factor values by levels ( otherwise I would have 144 levels and that would be too much and not relevant)

Thank you,

Comment: I think generally factors are for categorical or ordinal variables. This can be represented by numbers, for example if 1 stands for voting intention for party 1 and "2" for party 2 and so on (I would change the numbers for the party names though). Seconds are a continuous variable and should be kept as numeric or as integer if fractions are not present. From a programming perspective there is no real difference, so I think SO might be the wrong site to ask this question.

Comment: Completely agree with @JBGruber. Only thing I would like to add is bout the " if they always take integer values and in a narrow range. " part. I can imagine this refers to the usage of rating scales. It is often just assumed they have an underlying continuous scaling and therefore can be used as continuous variables. Strictly speaking that is incorrect.

Comment: What is NSP ?  ?

Comment: I meant NSM.
I am sorry for posting in the wrong place, Thank youfor the answer !

Comment: For NSM, my answer would be "it depends on what you want to do with the data". If you want to fit a model to predict an outcome, then you have many choices. Fit NSM as a continuous variable and inspect the results. If you think it has a linear relationship with the outcome, then keep it as is. If however you think values from midnight to 6am give very similar outcomes, and different to those from 6am to 6pm, or 6pm back to midnight, then converting NSM into a factor with 3 levels may give a better fit. However, keeping variables as continuous has a lot appeal: such as with GAMs.

Answer (score 0):

I generally only convert a variable to a factor if one or more of the following are true:

- the values of the variable represent some form of grouping, i.e. the variable is categorical in nature.
- there are substantial memory savings to be had - this is usually the case where character variables have been used to identify group levels.
- the variable is numeric in nature, but is highly non-linear, and there's no better way of entering it into a model than to convert it to a factor with one or two meaningful cut-points chosen.

However, manipulting factor variables can be more fiddly than characters or integers, so I tend to save the factoring until the very end, unless memory pressures force my hand.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been self-learning just like you and as per my understanding of this topic it's better to use factors when we have limited nominal/categorical values especially in the case of character vectors like gender ("Male", "Female"). This saves us from comparison errors involved in characters like case sensitivity or spelling mistakes.

Also, internally factors and integers work in the same way and if there are limited categorical integer values then it's suggested to use factors in order to have more meaningful data through levels. In your case, my opinion is to use Integers than factors as there are too many of levels to attach any meaningful information even if its required.

Finally you should be the best judge to decide if you should use factors in your code as you'd know where exactly you're going to use them again in your program as some algorithms explicitly demand factors than character vectors.